# ROS Answers SE migration: EV3 not NTX

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am very new to robotics and purchased an EV3 a few months back, since I am coming from a PHP background, I would really like to experiment using an os like ROS. I have found information about NTX, but I can't seem to find any instructions for installing ROS on EV3.

A bit of guidance will be very helpful.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161756/ev3-not-ntx/) by [NewEV3](https://answers.ros.org/users/16896/newev3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - this is a great question - and one that I am trying to work the answer out for.. I found this: https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev its a linux distro for the EV3 that should work if you have a microSD and follow the instructions - take a look at this error first though: https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev/issues/63 - which helped - but I haven’t gotten past the boot screen yet, you may have more luck.. The next step for me would be then to get a wifi dongle working and see how I can send commands to the EV3 real time.. I was thinking of trying to install a light version of ROS on the SD card - but I am now sure if that is a good idea either.. Will definitely follow up as soon as I have anything more to offer.

---

Originally posted by [kleinash](https://answers.ros.org/users/2345/kleinash/) with karma: 56 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NewEV3](https://answers.ros.org/users/16896/newev3/) on 2014-06-02**:
Hello,

Thank you for your insight, I will give this a try this week. Please keep me updated on your progress.